# Request sent to the search content service failed (access denied)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, hybrid-solution

We have configured SharePoint Hybrid Search (on premise 2013 with SharePoint Online) .

When crawling a site collection content source, in my crawl logs, I get the following error

> "Request sent to the search content service failed (access denied)"

Out of 5000 items, more than half of the items had this error.

Our SP Server connects through the proxy. Also, I have logged into the system with the service account(Search service running on) and configured IE to use proxy settings and able to connect to site.

[How I Configured Hybrid Search ?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720906.aspx)

Will any information be useful?

**Update** :
In the successive incremental crawls, there were few more items(100 or something) crawled and the number of errors got less. Not sure till how long when all the items are crawled.